# mvc 4 partial views with ajax model binding and validation summary not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, model-binding

I have one page with 3 partial views.  I need to obviously avoid id clashes.  All three partial views and the main page have their own view model.  In the main view a button click will update a div's html that is initially hidden with an ajax call to the controller to return a partial view  (onSuccess: div.html(data) ).  In that partial view I can update the model by submitting to the controller.  I can see the data is correctly coming through.

If I intentionally leave a required field blank and submit the partial view then it is supposed to come back and display errors in the validation summary or on the fields.

Like if I add this in the controller before returning the model:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "There was an error submitting data to the database.");
```

That works if I don't modify the binding prefix.

It doesn't work if I modify the binding prefix like the following methods:
In the controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveSchedHeaderSub([Bind(Prefix="SHS")]CPSchedHeaderSubViewModel theModel)
```

In the partial view:

```
@{ ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "SHS";}
```

Yes I have all the correct JavaScript files.  The model state errors just aren't working in this scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I just need to prefix the names of the fields the best way possible in this scenario.

I am a long time reader and this is my first question.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well after hours of this situation, I got the validation summary to show.  On all of my other web pages without returning a view via ajax the Validation Summary was set like: @Html.ValidationSummary(true) to exclude property errors.  For this ajax partial view I have to change it to False to display the summary?